# Can we disable external authentication completely in salt_api cherrypy?

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to using salt api in which it asks for login before using any other api. Is it possible to disable it?

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/netapi/all/salt.netapi.rest_cherrypy.html#salt.netapi.rest_cherrypy.app.Run

I tried to go through documentation but no luck.

Comment: Never used it, but there is [salt.auth.auto](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/auth/all/salt.auth.auto.html#module-salt.auth.auto) - maybe this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving your API wide open in very inadvisable and probably unsupported in Salt without changing the source code.

My suggestion would be to setup [Salt's External Authentication System (eAuth)](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/eauth/index.html#acl-eauth), either with local users or from LDAP.

Once you have that configured you can always login to the Salt API to receive a token and use that to authenticate to the API in any additional calls.

Best example taken from Salt's [rest_cherrypy](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/netapi/all/salt.netapi.rest_cherrypy.html#rest-cherrypy-auth):

```
# Write the cookie file:
curl -sSk https://localhost:8000/login \
      -c ~/cookies.txt \
      -H 'Accept: application/x-yaml' \
      -d username=saltdev \
      -d password=saltdev \
      -d eauth=auto

# Read the cookie file:
curl -sSk https://localhost:8000 \
      -b ~/cookies.txt \
      -H 'Accept: application/x-yaml' \
      -d client=local \
      -d tgt='*' \
      -d fun=test.ping
```

Configuring HTTPS is also highly advisable.